# Find all called methods of a class in project

Tags: java, eclipse, code-analysis

In the process of refactoring large portions of a Java project, I am trying to get a sense of how many methods of a specific library class' methods my project uses. In Eclipse, I can open the Call Hierarchy for a method using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, which does exactly what I want, but for a single method. On the other hand, I can find all references to a given class in my workspace using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (or in the project through the right-click context menu), but without any information on how the class or objects hereof are used.

In other words, it seems like I'm trying to find a feature that combines the two - find all references to a class, and then which methods (if any) are called on the class or objects hereof within the scope of that reference. Does such a feature exist in Eclipse (or any other (free) IDE)?

Edit: I realize the question may be a bit cryptic, so here's a pseudo code description of the basic idea:

```
findMethodCalls(Class c)
1.   result = empty list of method names
2.   for each method m in c
3.     if "Open Call Hierarchy" for m is non-empty
4.       result.add(m);
5.   return result;
```

Comment: Intellij has find usages of a class or interface. That will consider all usages.

Comment: @Jayan - Assuming you mean "Find Usages" from the right-click context menu, it appears to be the same as Eclipse's reference finding. It groups the usages nicely, but does not seem to include any method calls made on the objects of the given type, only stuff like local variable declarations, method parameters, instanceof usage, etc. I may be missing something though.